# Stopping variable from being updated by dynamic

Tags: dynamic

I'm trying to write a script that will dynamically update, except for one variable, say `y` in a block

```
Dynamic@F[x,y]
```

So that it doesn't get re-evaluated when I reopen the notebook.

Comment: Perhaps, the option TrackedSymbols

Comment: Good idea, but what if I have only one symbol and I'd like it to be untracked? In other words I'd like `F` to evaluate, but `x` not.

Comment: then you still use `Dynamic[F[x, y], TrackedSymbols :> {F}]` and now only changes in `F` trigger an update

Answer (score 1):

You might want to describe the problem you are trying to solve in more detail, the comments indicate that people aren't sure about that. Here is what I think could be what you are after:

```
With[{x = x},Dynamic[f[x, y]]]
```

using `With` you can insert the current value of `x` into the `Dynamic` as a constant, so it will not change anymore. Whenever the definitions for `y` or `f` change, the `Dynamic` will fire using the value of `x` which it had at evaluation time of the above expression. There are several other techniques to achieve the same thing, but I think `With` is probably the easiest of these to understand...